# How to re-arrange images in gallery after changing the GMT time zone?

Tags: gallery, time-zones

I travel to another country and take photos for a few days. After that I change the tike zone of my phone.

Since then, photos in my gallery are mixed up!?

I open the DCIM folder and see that the cause is that gallery sorts images by the filename and filenames are named after the taken time when the photo is captured.

How can I get photos updated with the time zone changed?

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** This is based on Samsung Galaxy S4 (Android 4.2.2)

In Gallery, click All beside the Gallery (flower) icon. Then, press left menu button, and select `Sort by latest` (If you see `Sort by oldest`, then your pictures are already sorted by latest.

Comment: Could find this on my phone

Comment: @Nam G. VU You found it? Good! Did it fix your problem?

Comment: I'm sorry I mistype the word not :( Updated my comment @geffchang

Comment: Could not find this on my phone